# which is better to build 2D animations in android through JAVA or XML code?

Tags: android

Hi i am developing 2D user interface for android using java but it takes some time so can i use XML code instead of that and can it makes any difference in user interface looks.

Comment: The question is very unclear, hard to understand what you're asking for. Tell us more about what you're working on and what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: If you are talking about performance have a look at my question here: http://stackoverflow.com/q/8760841/813951

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are talking about the interface elements then do not use Java. Java just might make it worse. 
If you are talking about animations then you can use either Java or XML. It depends on your use case scenario.

Comment: ok thanks and for static layouts XML is better to use i guess?

Comment: "java just might make it worse": please elaborate on this claim.

Comment: @Sahil better in which sense? It certainly is better for modifiability, allows you to use the GUI graphical editor, and in general is the recommended approach.

Comment: With Java you need to set your interface dimensions properly keeping in mind the appropriate dpscale. It's cumbersome and if you don't do this then your layout will look weird on different screens. Along with that there is the difficulty to code and iterate on a GUI written in Java entirely as it can not take advantage of GUI preview tools in Eclipse and IntelliJ IDEs.