# How to tell Proguard to comment some lines in code?

Tags: android, proguard

In my application I'm using a class `Cs` for doing the logging part.
It already has a `DEBUG` field which is set to true/false depending on the build type.

Everything is working good so far but I want to improve this a bit so I'm trying to find way to automatically comment these lines. This will avoid some problems that might appear due a log.
Ex:

```
1. StringBuilder messages = getSomeMessages()
2. Cs.e(TAG, messages.toString());
```

When line 2 is commented the app won't crash if the `messages` is null.
  Also if I remove these lines in release but keep them in debug version it will be hard to detect the errors from stacktrace because the lines number won't match anymore.

My question is: It is possible to tell Proguard to comment all the lines which start with some characters (Cs in my case)?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

> Also if I remove these lines in release but keep them in debug version it will be hard to detect the errors from stacktrace because the lines number won't match anymore.

For starters, your assumption that commented lines would make it into the compiled class/dex files [is incorrect](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10611087/what-happens-to-comments-after-the-java-files-are-compiled-in-android). This will not differ between debug and release builds.

Secondly, by optimising and/or obfuscating, Proguard will most likely modify your code in such a way that line numbers will no longer match up with your original source. That's exactly why it generates a *mapping* file (generally just `mapping.txt`): so that a stack trace can be de-obfuscated (or: [retraced](http://proguard.sourceforge.net/manual/retrace/introduction.html)).

> When line 2 is commented the app won't crash if the messages is null.

```
 StringBuilder messages = getSomeMessages()
 Cs.e(TAG, messages.toString());
```

Correct. But if you're after *improving* your code and its robustness, why not guard the log with a `null` check?

For example: only log something if there are actually messages:

```
if (messages != null) Cs.e(TAG, messages.toString());
```

Or: log some indication that there were no messages:

```
Cs.e(TAG, messages != null ? messages.toString() : "<empty>");
```

I'm not sure what kind of logger `Cs` wraps, but consider leveraging the functionality of Android's own [`Log`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/Log.html) class. That is, if you're really logging an error for development purposes, using *Verbose* or *Debug* log levels will make more sense. These are automatically stripped away (at resp. compilation time and runtime) and as such you don't have to worry about accidentally generating an exception in your production builds when logging.

Alternative, you can also easily wrap any debug logging with a check for the auto-generated `BuildConfig.DEBUG` flag - it sounds like you're already doing that.